# Position a form next to a <ul> element

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I'm creating a navbar using Twitter bootstrap, I have some costume CSS implemented in it:

```
<nav id="Navbar" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
     <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
     <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
           <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse">
           <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
           <span class="icon-bar"></span>
           <span class="icon-bar"></span>
           <span class="icon-bar"></span>
           </button>
           <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://www.linkedin.com/in/johntk86" >John Kiernan</a>
        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
           <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="Navmenu">
              <li  id="active"><a href="index.html" >Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="apps.html" >Apps</a></li>
              <li><a href="qualifications.html" >Qualifications</a></li>
              <li ><a data-toggle="modal"  data-target="#myModal">Contact</a></li>
           </ul>
              <form id="search" action="#" method="post">
                    <div id="label"><i class="fa fa-search" for="search-terms" id="search-label"></i></div>
                    <div id="input"><input type="text" name="search-terms" id="search-terms" placeholder="Enter search terms..."></div>
           </form>
           <nav>
              <div id="social-buttons">
                 <ul class="social list-inline">
                    <li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/"><i class="fa fa-stack-overflow"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://linkedin.com/"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://twitter.com/"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://github.com/"><i class="fa fa-github-alt"></i> </a></li>
                    <li><a  href="#">

                        </a>
                    </li>
                 </ul>
              </div>
           </nav>
        </div>
     </div>
  </nav>
```

I have a form implemented before my social media buttons, I'm trying to get the form to line up next to `<div id="social-buttons">` in my navbar and have it responsive.

I modified the example found [here](http://callmenick.com/post/expanding-search-bar-using-css-transitions) to fit my code.

Is this achievable? I've been trying in vain for hours.

JS:

```
(function(window){

// get vars
var searchEl = document.querySelector("#input");
var labelEl = document.querySelector("#label");

// register clicks and toggle classes
labelEl.addEventListener("click",function(){
    console.log("Im in here");
    if (classie.has(searchEl,"focus")) {
        classie.remove(searchEl,"focus");
        classie.remove(labelEl,"active");
    } else {
        classie.add(searchEl,"focus");
        classie.add(labelEl,"active");
    }
});

// register clicks outisde search box, and toggle correct classes
document.addEventListener("click",function(e){
    var clickedID = e.target.id;
    if (clickedID != "search-terms" && clickedID != "search-label") {
        if (classie.has(searchEl,"focus")) {
            classie.remove(searchEl,"focus");
            classie.remove(labelEl,"active");
        }
    }
});
}(window));
```

CSS:

```
 #search {
    position: absolute;
    color: #888888;
    left: 20px;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-top: 15px;
}
#label {
    width: 60px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 60;
}

#input {
    position: relative;
    top: 20;
    left: 60px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 40px;
    z-index: 5;
    overflow: hidden;

}
    #input input {
        position: relative;
        top: 0;
        left: -450px;
        width: 450px;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        margin: 20;
        padding: 0 10px;
        border: none;
        background-color: #eee;
        color: #000000;
        font-size: 18px;
        backface-visibility: none;
        border-radius: 0;
        transition: left 0;

    }

    #input input:focus {
        outline: none
    }

    #input.focus {
        z-index: 20
    }

    #input.focus input {
        left: 0;
        transition: left 0.3s;
    }
```

Comment: You should post all of the code you're working with including your JS in a working example.

Comment: I've added all of the relevant the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to do something like this which would mean placing your form inside the navbar-header div and go from there as far as positioning the form and the input so it covers your links.

Hopefully this helps.

```js
$(".btn-search").click(function(e) {
  $("#search-input, #btn-go").fadeToggle();
});
```

```css
body {
  padding-top: 60px;
}
.navbar.navbar-custom {
  border: none;
}
.navbar.navbar-custom .navbar-toggle {
  z-index: 1;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  padding: 7.5px 5px 0 0;
}
.navbar.navbar-custom .formSearch {
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
.btn.btn-search,
.btn.btn-search:hover,
.btn.btn-search:focus {
  background: none;
  height: 50px;
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
}
.navbar.navbar-custom #search-input {
  height: 50px;
  background: #444;
  color: #fff;
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  border: none;
  display: none;
}
.navbar.navbar-custom #search-input:focus {
  height: 50px;
  background: #444;
  color: #f00;
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  border: none;
  bottom: 0;
  display: none;
}
.navbar.navbar-custom .input-group-btn #btn-go {
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none;
  background: rgba(17, 18, 19, 1) color: #fff;
  display: none;
}
.navbar.navbar-custom .navbar-toggle i {
  color: #fff;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar.navbar-custom .nav.navbar-left {
    margin-left: 25px;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar.navbar-custom #social-nav > li {
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-nav" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>

        <i class="fa fa-align-right"></i>

      </button>
      <form class="formSearch" role="search"> <span class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-search" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>

        </button>
        </span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control hasclear" id="search-input" placeholder="Search for..."> <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" id="btn-go" type="button"> Search</button>
      </span>
        </span>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-nav">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
        <li id="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="apps.html">Apps</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="qualifications.html">Qualifications</a>

        </li>
        <li><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Contact</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" id="social-nav">
        <li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/"><i class="fa fa-stack-overflow"></i></a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="http://linkedin.com/"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="http://twitter.com/"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="http://github.com/"><i class="fa fa-github-alt"></i> </a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="container">
  <div class="well well-lg">
    <h1>Boostrap Search Bar</h1>

  </div>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
    has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer
    took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset
    sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
    standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
    It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the
    printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries,
    but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
    including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled
    it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages,
    and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since
    the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in
    the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
    industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic
    typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem
    Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
    It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer
    took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset
    sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
    standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
    It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the
    printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries,
    but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
    including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Absolute gent, this is perfect, thought I wasted a whole day for nothing. thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible, there are many ways you could approach it but I would do something like this:

**HTML:**

```
<nav id="Navbar" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://www.linkedin.com/in/johntk86" >John Kiernan</a>
    </div>
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="Navmenu">
        <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="apps.html" >Apps</a></li>
        <li><a href="qualifications.html" >Qualifications</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="modal"  data-target="#myModal">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="form-container">
        <form id="search" action="#" method="post">
          <div id="label"><i class="fa fa-search" for="search-terms" id="search-label"></i></div>
          <div id="input"><input type="text" name="search-terms" id="search-terms" placeholder="Enter search terms..."></div>
        </form>
        <div id="social-buttons">
          <ul class="social list-inline">
            <li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/"><i class="fa fa-stack-overflow"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="http://linkedin.com/"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="http://twitter.com/"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="http://github.com/"><i class="fa fa-github-alt"></i> </a></li>
            <li><a  href="#"></a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

**CSS:**

```
form, form > div {
  display:inline-block;
}
.form-container {
  display:table;
  height:50px;
  float:right;
}
  .form-container > form, .form-container > div {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
  }
#social-buttons ul {
  margin:0;
}
```

I removed the `nav` wrap from around your social buttons because it is unnecessary and Bootstrap gives nav elements 100% width, which you don't want in this case since you want the buttons to be inline with the other elements. Additionally, I have wrapped the `form` and `social-buttons` div in a container, which can be treated as a table to take care of the vertical centering and also floated to the right.

## [Bootply Example](http://www.bootply.com/X749fTcmxr)

Comment: I have javascript hiding the input box and displaying it when the button is clicked, the input box goes over my media buttons (I want this effect)
But even when the input box is not displayed the media button are unresponsive, is there a way to bring the media button to the front?